# How to use type definitions when importing/requiring files (not modules) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have three files:

**a.js**

```
var moduleb=require('./b.js')
moduleb.func('should_be_a_string_and_return_a_boolen')
```

**b.js**

```
 function func(arg){
         return arg
 }
 module.exports={func}
```

**b.d.ts**

```
 declare function fnc(arg:string):boolean
```

---

#### The question:

How I make TypeScript compiler to understands the type definition in `b.d.ts` and connect it to the exported values in `b.js`?

#### What I'm trying to achieve?

I'm using `create-react-app` and I want to add type definition to Components so that I can get IntelliSense, to all the props of the components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modules (both CommonJS and ES) that have respective .d.ts typings can be imported as usual in TypeScript:

```
import * as moduleb from './b.js';
```

Or:

```
import moduleb = require('./b.js');
```

While `require` without `import` statement is supposed to be used for modules that don't have typings and synchronous dynamic imports.